# JQuery Mocking

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, mocking

I am looking for a **mature** framework that can do Javascript mocking, especially on AJAX and JSON area.

Is there any existing mocking framework for Javascript ( and/ or JQuery) that **you are used and can recommend**?

**Edit: I have evaluated [jqmock](http://code.google.com/p/jqmock/) and [jqunit](http://code.google.com/p/jqunit/). It seems that it's the only framework that can do [basic library mocking and stubbing](http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2009/06/mocking-and-stubbing-in-javascript.html), but it can't do AJAX call.**

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptjunkie/ff452703 has a nice article on jQuery TDD

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here are some links that might help you:

[amok](http://code.google.com/p/amok/) (claims to have ajax support)

[fakequery](http://code.google.com/p/fakequery/)

[QUnit](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit)

[JSMock](http://jsmock.sourceforge.net/)

[qMock](http://code.google.com/p/qmock/wiki/About_qMock)

[jqunit](http://code.google.com/p/jqunit/) + [jqmock](http://code.google.com/p/jqmock/)

---

Other javascript testing "frameworks"

[jqunit](http://code.google.com/p/jqunit/)

[Jack](http://boss.bekk.no/display/BOSS/Jack)

[YUI Test](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuitest/)

[JSSpec](http://jania.pe.kr/aw/moin.cgi/JSSpec)

Comment: Haven't tried but jquery-mockjax might be good for ajax mocking? https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax

Answer (score 4):

I prefer modular code. Modular code is easy to mock!

```
var function fetchAjaxData(){
  // Perform ajax request.
  // Call 'update' with the data in question.
}

var update = function(ajaxData){
  // do things with ajaxData
}
```

With this kind of code, all you need to do is to call the 'update' function to mock a ajax request.

Comment: … except when the code you test is abstracted away inside e.g. an IIFE and opening it up for testing would break domain design. So one tends to go for the mocking of dependencies route, which this would be about.

Answer (score 2):

Mocking is included in the [jasmine](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/%20jasmine) testframework too.
I used it myself to mock out jQuery.ajax:

```
spyOn(jQuery, 'ajax').andCallFake(function(value) {
    value.success(data);
});
```